# Count Number of selected Options in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple dropdowns with a similar name, I want to count the number of dropdowns which have an option selected.

For example,

```
<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect1" id="customSelect1">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect2" id="customSelect2">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect3" id="customSelect3">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Here I want to count the number of only those drop downs which have selected value 1 or 2.

Comment: have tried `$("#customSelect1 option").length` ?

Comment: yes, that is returning the total count of dropdown options, not just the selected ones.

Comment: but what do you mean by selected? if they are rendered in this way, actually they are all selected with value of 0

Comment: @quirimo, for example in dropdown One I select option 2, and in dropdown Two selected option 1, and  I leave dropdown 3 as it is, then I want to count how many among these 3 have any option selected except 0, which is a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to get all the select whose *selectedIndex* is greater than 0 and the get the length:

```js
$('.custom_select').change(function(){
  var c = $('.custom_select').filter((i,s) => $(s)[0].selectedIndex > 0).length;
  console.log(c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect1" id="customSelect1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect2" id="customSelect2">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect3" id="customSelect3">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the shortest one, but can I combine this with .on ('change') ?

Comment: @DeepakSingh, yes, you can simply change *click* to *change*.....updated the answer....please check.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check the length of selected option except option having value = 0 by `$(".custom_select>option:not([value='0']):selected").length`

```js
console.log($(".custom_select>option:not([value='0']):selected").length)
$(".custom_select").off("change").on("change", function(){
 console.log($(".custom_select>option:not([value='0']):selected").length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect1" id="customSelect1">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect2" id="customSelect2">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect3" id="customSelect3">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice answer. :)

Comment: Thank you, Very clean answer :)  Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If for you `0` is the disabled/default value, you can use the below, but I would suggest you to use a disabled selected option as default/begin option:

```js
function onPressed() {
  console.log($('.custom_select option[value!="0"]:selected').length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect2" id="customSelect2">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect3" id="customSelect3">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<button onclick="onPressed()">Click for showing selected ones</button>
```

Comment: yeah that's changed after I wrote the first answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? This example will count dropdown with selected value 1 or 2:

```js
$('.custom_select').change(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $.each($(".custom_select option:selected"), function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == 1 || $(this).val() == 2) {
      ++count;
    }
  });
  console.log('Dropdown count = ' + count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect1" id="customSelect1">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect2" id="customSelect2">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect3" id="customSelect3">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Better you read the code before copy & paste...  code is working.

Answer (score 0):

By default the first option is always selected.So add another `option` if `0` is valid option.Since there is a common class across all the select use `document.getElementsByClassName` and use `filter` to get the `select` whose value is not empty

```js
function getSelected() {
  // using spread operator to convert collection to array
  // using array filter methods to create a new array with select which have value
  let k = [...document.getElementsByClassName('custom_select')].filter(item => {
    return item.value !== ''
  })
  // this will give number of selects whose value is nit empty
  console.log(k.length)


}
```

```html
<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect1" id="customSelect1">
  <option value=''>Selected</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect2" id="customSelect2">
  <option value=''>Selected</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect3" id="customSelect3">
  <option value=''>Selected</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<button onclick='getSelected()'>Get Selected</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".custom_select").change(function() {
let selectedDropDownCount = 0;
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".custom_select");
x.forEach( y => {
if($("#"+ y.getAttribute("id")).val() != "0")
{
selectedDropDownCount++;
}
}
)
alert("Count : " + selectedDropDownCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect1" id="customSelect1">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect2" id="customSelect2">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect3" id="customSelect3">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version using [JQuery filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), but this one test for a set of matched values.

```js
$('.custom_select').change(function()
{
    var matchs = $('.custom_select').filter((i, e) =>
    {
        return ["1", "2"].includes($(e).val());
    });

    console.log(matchs.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect1" id="customSelect1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect2" id="customSelect2">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="custom_select" name="customSelect3" id="customSelect3">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```